# Cannot retrieve all the data from Hashtable

Tags: c, algorithm

I am trying to code an algorithm in C that reads a huge file ( more than 750.000 lines) , separates each line by some specified delimiters , and saves the data into a structure , which is then saved into a `Hashtable`. Everything goes fine until I want to print one specific data for each row of the `Hashtable`: the output is good for some rows , but the console is just printing some random symbols for others (which means memory leaks maybe? ).

I am trying to figure what can cause this problem. If I isolate the code that separate the line and saves it into the structure, and execute it for each line separately, it works fine, everything is printed as expected.

I have also tried to do it without dynamic allocation but it works a bit better with it as I was getting the infamous "Segmentation fault"

Here is the code that splits the line and saves it:

```
unsigned int hash(unsigned int id) {
    unsigned int hashage = 5381; //Valeur arbitraire
    unsigned int mdop = 10; //faire un modulo obtenir l'unite
    int idtmp = id;
    while (mdop < id) {
        idtmp = id%mdop;
        hashage = ((hashage << 6) + hashage) + idtmp;
        mdop *= 10;
    }

    return hashage % NB_CASES_HASH;
}

void initiate_hashtable(Hashtable hashtable) {
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < NB_CASES_HASH; i++) {
        hashtable[i] = NULL;
    }
}

void ajout_entete(Liste *liste, Oeuvre *oeuvre) {
    Liste p = malloc(sizeof(Cellule));
    if (!p) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    p->oeuvre = *oeuvre;
    p->suiv = *liste;
    //Si on imprime ici , tout va bien , les données sont correctes
    *liste = p;
}

void ajout_annee(Liste *liste, Oeuvre *oeuvre) { //ajout trié par année pour   recherche plus rapide
    if (!(*liste) || oeuvre->year <= (*liste)->oeuvre.year)
        ajout_entete(liste,oeuvre);
    else {
        if (oeuvre->year >= (*liste)->oeuvre.year)
            ajout_annee(&(*liste)->suiv, &oeuvre);
    }
}

Oeuvre peuple_oeuvre(char line[MAX_CHARS_LINE]) {
    int i = 0, j = 1, cmpt = 0;
    char strings[CHAMPS_OEUVRE][MAX_SIZE];
    char carac = *(line);
    char mot[MAX_SIZE];
    mot[0] = carac;
    bool isSuivi = false;
    Oeuvre oeuvre;

    while (carac != '\n') {
        if (carac == ',') {
            if(isSuivi) {
                mot[j - 1] = '\"';
                mot[j] = '\0';
                isSuivi = false;
            } else
                mot[j - 1] = '\0';

            strcpy(strings[i], mot);
            j = 0;
            i++;
        } else
        if (carac == '\"') {
            cmpt++;
            carac = *(line + cmpt);
            while (carac != '\"') {
                mot[j] = carac;
                j++;
                cmpt++;
                carac = *(line + cmpt);
            }
            isSuivi = true;
        }
        cmpt++;
        carac = *(line + cmpt);
        mot[j] = carac;
        j++;
    }
    mot[j] = '\0';
    strcpy(strings[i], mot);

    //Assignation des valeurs :

    oeuvre.id = atoi(strings[0]);
    oeuvre.accession_number = strdup(strings[1]);
    oeuvre.artiste.nomArtiste = strdup(strings[2]);
    oeuvre.artiste.artistRole = strdup(strings[3]);
    oeuvre.artiste.artistId = atoi(strings[4]);
    oeuvre.titre = strdup(strings[5]);
    oeuvre.url = strdup(strings[CHAMPS_OEUVRE]);
    oeuvre.year = atoi(strings[9]);

    return oeuvre;
}

void peuple_hashtable(Hashtable hashtable) { // Peuplement par redirection
    char ligne[MAX_CHARS_LINE];
    fgets(ligne, MAX_CHARS_LINE, stdin);
    Oeuvre *oeuvre = malloc(sizeof(Oeuvre));
    int hashNum;
    while (fgets(ligne, MAX_CHARS_LINE, stdin)) {
        *oeuvre = peuple_oeuvre(ligne);
        hashNum = hash(oeuvre->artiste.artistId);
        ajout_annee(&hashtable[hashNum], oeuvre);
    }
}

int main() {
    Hashtable hashtable;
    initiate_hashtable(hashtable);
    peuple_hashtable(hashtable);
    return 0; 
}
```

And the Oeuvre structure looks like this :

```
typedef struct oeuvre {
    unsigned int id;
    char *accession_number;
    Artiste artiste;
    char *titre;
    int year;
    char *url;
} Oeuvre;

typedef Liste Hashtable[NB_CASES_HASH];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: malloc(strlen(strings[3])*sizeof(char *)); => malloc(strlen(strings[3])*sizeof(char));   Get rid of * on every char * in malloc statements.  You need to allocate memory for characters, not char pointer.

Comment: So may bugs, so little time...

Comment: Removing the * throws me a core dumped !

Comment: Please learn C (and forget your Java courses)

Comment: Learning starts by doing mistakes :)

Comment: On second thought: your code looks reasonable, except for the tokeniser. You should learn how to handle characters an strings in C. The stdlib string functions could help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my issue by declaring the Oeuvre structure like this

```
typedef struct oeuvre {
unsigned int id;
char accession_number[MAX_CHARS];
Artiste artiste;
char titre[MAX_CHARS];
int year;
char url[MAX_CHARS];
 } Oeuvre;
```

with MAX_CHARS referring to a large number. 
So I believe I was not properly allocating the strings before using them, which made them to point to random adresses , resulting in those weird outputs but no error. I also believe that another way of solving this would be to dynamically allocate the chars for each Oeuvre in my function.

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems in your code.

- If `line` does not contain a newline or if a double quote is missing, the behavior is undefined.
- You do not initialize the string array: if the description has missing fields, the behavior is undefined.
- In the part where you save the structure fields, your allocation code is incorrect: you must allocate one more character than the length of the string, `strlen(string[0]) + 1` instead of `strlen(string[0]) * sizeof(char*)`.

It would be much simpler to use the POSIX function `strdup()`:

```
// Assigning the values:

oeuvre.id = atoi(strings[0]);
oeuvre.accession_number = strdup(strings[1]);
oeuvre.artiste.nomArtiste = strdup(strings[2]);
oeuvre.artiste.artistRole = strdup(strings[3]);
oeuvre.artiste.artistId = atoi(strings[4]);
oeuvre.titre = strdup(strings[5]);
oeuvre.url = strdup(strings[CHAMPS_OEUVRE]));
oeuvre.year = atoi(strings[9]);
```

Comment: Tried your solution but I have still a lot of entry that comes out as weird symbols... Maybe it is the assignation in the hashtable that cause the problem , since if I print the data outside of the hashtable , everything comes fine .

Line is always filled as I am using an fgets to retrieve every line from stdin in the main .

Which string array are you referring to ?

Comment: @tarzan212:  Unless you post a complete program including the hashtable implementation and usage, issues outside the posted function cannot be investigated.

Comment: Just added the full code (except the main) to the main post !

Comment: @tarzan212: A complete program needs a `main()` function.